# Import records from online MySQL database into MS Access database

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, relational-database

I am using an MS Access database to manage my contacts, specifically email lists. I use a self hosted email application (Sendy) to send email for my customers.

I would like to know if it would be possible to import the Campaign Name and Last Send Date for an email record.

For example if bob@email.com exists in the Access database, I would like to query the Sendy application date import the Campaign that Bob received and the last time he was sent an email.

Are there are technical or cross-compatibility issues that won't make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Access can link to an external MySQL database for which one has privileges.  See the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html) on how to use Access with MySQL. All it takes is installing an ODBC connector and Access's External Data, ODBC Database menu option.